# How to send Protocol Buffer object using Winsock2?

Tags: sockets, visual-c++, protocol-buffers, winsock2

I am creating a client server app using a simple socket to transfer Protocol Buffer objects between C++ and Java. I have it created on the Java side both as the client and receiver. I even got the Java to send to C++ but I am having trouble with sending from C++ to Java. Not sure how to write it. First I am sending the size and then reading the proto object.

I am using Visual Studio C++ 2008. DataGram and Bookmartlet are my proto objects.

Here is my C++ Sender Client

int loopt = 99;

```
do {
    DataGram dataGram;
    dataGram.set_state("ACK");

    time ( &rawtime );
    dataGram.set_status(ctime(&rawtime));
    Bookmarklet* bookmarklet = dataGram.mutable_bookmarklet();
    bookmarklet->set_name("TEST");
    bookmarklet->set_utl("TEST");
    dataGram.SerializeToArray(recvbuf,recvbuflen);
    dataGram.ByteSize();
    //Trouble SPOT  
    send(ConnectSocket,size,1,0);
    send(ConnectSocket,recvbuf,recvbuflen,0);
} while (loopt > 0);
```

This is what I am trying to replicate from Java.

```
    OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
    try {
        int testtimes = 99;
        while (socket.isConnected() && testtimes > 0) {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // do nothing for 1000 miliseconds (1
                                // second)
            DataGram dataGram = null;
            Bookmarklet bookmarklet = Bookmarklet.newBuilder()
                    .setName("TEST").setUtl("TEST").build();
            if (testtimes % 2 == 0) {
                dataGram = DataGram.newBuilder().setState("ACK")
                        .setBookmarklet(bookmarklet)
                        .setStatus(new Date().toGMTString()).build();
            } else {
                dataGram = DataGram.newBuilder().setState("ACK")
                        .setStatus(new Date().toGMTString()).build();
            }
            output.write(dataGram.getSerializedSize());
            output.write(dataGram.toByteArray());
            testtimes--;

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Client in Java for Reference:

```
        InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
        int count = input.read();
        int counter = 0;
        while (count > 0) {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[count];

            count = input.read(buffer);
            DataGram dataGram = DataGram.parseFrom(buffer);

            Bookmarklet bookmarklet = null;
            if ((bookmarklet = dataGram.getBookmarklet()) != null) {
                System.out.println(bookmarklet.toString());
            }
            System.out.println(dataGram.getState() + " "
                    + dataGram.getStatus());
            count = input.read();
            System.out.println(++counter);

        }
```

Comment: You appear to never initialize 'size'. Should you have 'size = dataGram.ByteSize();' or some such?